# How come an Android APP doesn't need network permission, but still accesses internet?

Tags: android, security, permissions

I just downloaded this from Google Play.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xitek.wujiforum2013

It claims no need for Internet! But when I opened it, it is downloading contents from Internet! I tried to close all Internet connection, then the app can't display anything.

So why? Why an app without Internet permission can still access Internet!? This looks a security problem with Android itself, as if the app just claims to access local information but no Internet, user won't be aware that it will steal information by posting something at the background!

---

This is the permission screen, I don't see Internet permission. Is anybody seeing different permissions?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When I click the link *View Details* blow Permissions, networking permissions are listed.

Comment: I added the screen below. Do you see different permissions than me?

Comment: @AIMINPAN, you should always edit your question if you want to provide more details instead of posting an Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, since about a year ago apps don't need to request Internet permission anymore, which means that any app can use it, see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/190863/androids-app-permissions-were-just-simplified-now-theyre-much-less-secure/).

> Google has also given each app Internet access, effectively **removing the Internet access permission**. Oh, sure, Android **developers still have to declare they want Internet access** when putting together the app. But users can no longer see the Internet access permission when installing an app and current apps that don’t have Internet access can now gain Internet access with an automatic update without prompting you.

Us devs have to declare it on the manifest, but users aren't asked about it.

As many people stated on other answers, you can still see when they ask for it on the detailed permissions info, under "others" section.

Regarding security issues, remember that nowadays every app basically needs internet. We're in a time where it's the basic resource to make apps integrated and complete. Although Google has made it easier for the developers to use the internet, they still have a good app analysis when it comes to new apps trying to be published on Google Play. I have always thought that every app had the internet connection permission anyway.

Comment: Is there any formal announcement on this?

Comment: @AIMINPAN, aparently not. After searching a lot all i could find was someone saying what seemed to be right: so many apps use internet permission that it's not necessary to show it. There might me something on  Google Play Policy about it. If you get something from the internet you expect it to connect sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The program has many permissions including FULL network access

> Photos / Media / Files

modify or delete the contents of your USB

storage read the contents of your USB storage

> Other

view network connections

full network access